# Computed lists in Vue Draggable

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to make this todo app that should have drag and drop functionality. I want the user to be able to drag and drop the todos between three statuses: **initial**, **wip** and **done**.

I have the following data structure in my Vuex store:

```
projects: [],
todos: [
            {
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            createdBy: 'userId,
            id: 'todoId',
            refId: 'projectId',
            status: 'initial'
            },
            {
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            createdBy: 'userId,
            id: 'todoId',
            refId: 'projectId',
            status: 'wip'
            },
       ],
```

Instead of having three "raw" lists that are collecting each status with their todos, I'm instead collecting all the app's todos, no matter what status it has, in the same `todos` array. `status` is then the property that defines what status the todo has. I then use the following getter from the store to collect the todos that are assigned to the current project being viewed:

```
initTodos(state){
            return (projectId) => {
                return state.todos.filter((todo) => {
                    return todo.refId == projectId && todo.status == "initial"
                })
            }
        },
```

There are of course three getters in total for each status, this one being for the `initial` status. With Vue Draggable installed, I'm now fetching the getters in the `Project.vue` file with this computed method:

```
initTodos: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters.initTodos(this.id)
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log(value)
            this.$store.commit('updateList', value)
        }
    },
```

This is then looped through in the template with the following:

```
<draggable v-model="initTodos">
    <app-todo
    v-for="todo in initTodos"
    :key="todo.id"
    :id="todo.id"
    :description="todo.description">
    </app-todo>
</draggable>
```

I'm now wondering: is there any way to send the current order of the todos to the store when I drag and drop them, only updating the todos that this change is regarding? I can see when I log the `value` from `initTodos.set` that a new array with the new order is sent. But how do I update the todos with this new information? And how would this work when dragging and dropping to another list, like from `initial` to `wip` for example? It would then be between two computed lists that are fetched with corresponding getters.

Comment: You can use the move prop or update event to dispatch an action updating the store. https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#move     https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#event-object-demo